# ForkJoinPool, how to printout the ID of each working thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the fork/join framework. I saw the code below online, however, after I have run the code, the output seem to be out of order. So I was just wondering if there is any way to printout the ID of each working thread? the output is very confusing without ID to identify which thread is doing what.

**Source ::**

```
public class MyRecursiveTask extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRecursiveTask myRecursiveTask = new MyRecursiveTask(128);
        ForkJoinPool fjp1 = new ForkJoinPool();
        long mergedResult = fjp1.invoke(myRecursiveTask);



        System.out.println("mergedResult = " + mergedResult);
    }

    private long workLoad = 0;

    public MyRecursiveTask(long workLoad) {
        this.workLoad = workLoad;
    }

    protected Long compute() {

        //if work is above threshold, break tasks up into smaller tasks
        if (this.workLoad > 16) {
            System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.workLoad);

            List<MyRecursiveTask> subtasks
                    = new ArrayList<MyRecursiveTask>();
            subtasks.addAll(createSubtasks());

            for (MyRecursiveTask subtask : subtasks) {
                subtask.fork();
            }

            long result = 0;
            for (MyRecursiveTask subtask : subtasks) {
                result += subtask.join();
            }
            return result;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Doing workLoad myself: " + this.workLoad);
            return workLoad * 3;
        }
    }

    private List<MyRecursiveTask> createSubtasks() {
        List<MyRecursiveTask> subtasks
                = new ArrayList<MyRecursiveTask>();

        MyRecursiveTask subtask1 = new MyRecursiveTask(this.workLoad / 2);
        MyRecursiveTask subtask2 = new MyRecursiveTask(this.workLoad / 2);

        subtasks.add(subtask1);
        subtasks.add(subtask2);

        return subtasks;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Splitting workLoad : 128
Splitting workLoad : 64
Splitting workLoad : 32
Splitting workLoad : 64
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Splitting workLoad : 32
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Splitting workLoad : 32
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Splitting workLoad : 32
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Doing workLoad myself: 16
Doing workLoad myself: 16
mergedResult = 384
```

Comment: This can be useful `long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();`

Comment: Or even just `currentThread()`, which will print out useful information (including the ID, I think). `System.out.println("Task:"+ Thread.currentThread() );`

Comment: You should use a logging framework like `logback` or `log4j`. They let you define a log pattern that includes the thread name. Among other useful pieces of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compute()` is the main computation performed by this task. You should place the code to get the thread id here. Modify your `System.out.println` as below:

`System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.workLoad + " by thread " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());`
`System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.workLoad + " by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());`

My point of view, you should use thread name (`Thread.currentThread().getName()`) instead of thread id. Giving thread name we have more meaningful than the thread id.